# Check the ordering of 2 different keys in LinkedHashMap in O(1)

Tags: java, algorithm

In a LinkedHashMap, the keys are ordered by when they were inserted into the map.

For example, consider the following map.

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(1, 1);
map.put(2, 3);
map.put(7, 4);
map.put(5, 6);
```

So, my understanding of `LinkedHashMap` is that the keys are stored in the form a Doubly Linked List.

So, in this example, the keys would be ordered as `1<->2<->7<->5`

Now, my requirement is this. Given 2 keys from this map, is it possible to check which one came first or last?

For example, a function like the following

```
public boolean isFirst(int key1,int key2){
// logic to compute if key1 is first
}
```

Now, the above function can be done in O(n) easily by maintaining another map to get the order and compare it.

I want to do this operation in O(1). If it is possible, then should I maintain some other data structure to handle insertion, removal and updation of keys in the map ?

Comment: In LinkedHashMap you can't get the position of the key without iterating.

Comment: Have you taught of creating a dummy class, with Integer and static Position data members as key, and compare the positions?

Comment: You wrote _If it is possible, how to handle insertion, removal and updation_ on which one, your usual map or the technique you want for which complexity has to be O(1)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know which of the two keys is located _earlier than_ or _before_ the other?

Comment: @AlexRudenko Yes. That is my expected output

Comment: @vivek_23 I have updated the question slightly. Directly it is not possible to do this in O(1). But with some data structure, maybe. If so, how to do it?

Comment: Why does using another map to store the order have the time complexity `O(n)`?

Comment: @justhalf Consider the map to be like Map<Integer,Integer>. The key is the LinkedHashmap key and value would the iterated index. Now I will iterate the map and store this index value. After this, take any 2 keys - if the value of that key is less, it means that it came first.

Comment: The creation of the map is O(n), sure. But any query afterwards is O(1), right?

Comment: No, it is not that straighforward. What if new keys are inserted, old keys are removed?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Is it ok if we implement a class for this?

Comment: @vivek_23 Yup. Even a custom class is okay as long as the properties of the `LinkedHashMap`hold true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom class that extends [`LinkedHashMap`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java) and add the custom method `isFirst`. Internally, we keep a separate map as you already analyzed with a `timestamp` variable which acts like a timestamp for us(the second at which the key was added).

If the first key's timestamp is less than the second ones, we return `true` , else we return `false`.

**Class Snippet:**

```
class CustomMap<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V>{
    private Map<K,Integer> ord_map;
    private int timestamp = 0;
    CustomMap(){
        super();
        ord_map = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public V put(K key,V val){
        ord_map.put(key,timestamp++);
        return super.put(key,val);
    }
    
    public V remove(Object key){
        ord_map.remove(key);
        return super.remove(key);
    }
    
    public boolean isFirst(K key1,K key2) throws Exception{
        if(!ord_map.containsKey(key1)) throw new Exception(key1 + " does not exist.");
        if(!ord_map.containsKey(key2)) throw new Exception(key2 + " does not exist.");
        
        return ord_map.get(key1) < ord_map.get(key2);
    }
}
```

**Driver Code:**

```
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomMap<Integer,Integer> cmap = new CustomMap<>();
        try{
            cmap.put(1, 1);
            cmap.put(5, 6);
            cmap.put(2, 3);
            cmap.put(7, 4);
            System.out.println(cmap.isFirst(5,2));    
            cmap.remove(5);
            cmap.put(5,99);
            System.out.println(cmap.isFirst(5,2));  
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed!

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Glad to help. I have updated the internal definition to `Map<K,Integer>` to make it more generalized

Comment: Just had this doubt, this code will work even if I substitute `LinkedHashMap` with `HashMap` right?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Yes, it will work. Only difference is keys could be stored in any order internally.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya To be more precise, when you do a .`.keySet()`, the order could be in any fashion.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a solution based on HashMap for indexes, but it has O(N) complexity both in time and memory to populate the index map.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    static int index = 0;
    
    static Map<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    static void initIndexes(LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> map) {
        indexMap.clear();
        index = 0;
        map.keySet().forEach(x -> {indexMap.put(x, index++);});
    }
    
    static boolean isKeyBefore(int key1, int key2) {
        return indexMap.getOrDefault(key1, Integer.MAX_VALUE) < 
        indexMap.getOrDefault(key2, -1);
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put(1, 1);
        map.put(2, 3);
        map.put(7, 4);
        map.put(5, 6);
        
        initIndexes(map);
            
        System.out.println(indexMap);
        
        System.out.println(isKeyBefore(2, 5)); // true
        System.out.println(isKeyBefore(7, 1)); // false
        System.out.println(isKeyBefore(5, 3)); // key2 is not in the indexMap
        System.out.println(isKeyBefore(4, 2)); // key1 is not in the indexMap
        System.out.println(isKeyBefore(6, 8)); // both keys are not in the indexMap
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This one is what I had mentioned in the question comment. @vivek_23 's answer is O(1).